# Enter an input value with greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

I have some input values contained within a bunch of divs and a form.  I have a limited knowledge of js and would like to use greasemonkey to set the values when the page loads.

The following shows the order of divs and forms to get to the value.

```
<div data-role="page" id="finalTest">                    
  <div data-role="content">
    <form class="cmxform" id="ftForm">
      <div id="finalTestForOtherDiv" >
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="special-spacing">
                <div class="input-div">
                    <label id="finalTestBeforeAcTgrLabel" for="finalTestBeforeAcTg" data-insight="true" 
                        class="mandatory" data-default="mandatory"><img class="label-image" alt="" src="../Images/icon-alert.png" />AC V (T/G):</label>
                    <input type="text" id="finalTestBeforeAcTg" name="finalTestBeforeAcTg" value="" style="width:100px; display:inline-block;" 
                        data-bind="binder.BeforeAcTg"  data-bind-action-when-hidden="Ignore" />
                    <span class="ui-content" style="padding-left:7px;">V</span>
                    <div class="error-message"><ul></ul></div>

                </div>
```

Here is the script I've tried using but does nothing.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    Final Test
// @description Final test results
// @include https://techaccess.ad.qintra.com/WorkJobs/WorkJobs.aspx#finalTest
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeAcTg").value = "0.00";
```

Comment: Here is the code I'm using that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeAcTg").value = "your value";
```

Comment: Didn't think it would be that simple, thanks, I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work.  I've edited my original post to show the code as I have it

Comment: Check if your script does execute at all. What is the value of `document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeAcTg")`?

Comment: Oddly enough, I can do alert(document.getElementById("finalTestBeforeAcTg").value) and this will show 0.00, but it's not filling in the text box correctly.  The input box is still empty.

Comment: I also added more of the source html above to indicate what the entire section looks like that I'm working with

Comment: @PavelStrakhov What is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

If your script attempt is not working, it is likely because one or more of the following:

1. The `@include` is too restrictive.
2. The node does not exist yet.  Is AJAX active on the page?
3. Prerequisite javascript events must be triggered for the page to acknowledge or accept the new value.

For issue 1, change the script to:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Final Test
// @description Final test results
// @include     http://techaccess.ad.qintra.com/WorkJobs/*
// @include     https://techaccess.ad.qintra.com/WorkJobs/*
// ==/UserScript==

alert ("Script start.");

var finTestInput    = document.getElementById ("finalTestBeforeAcTg");
if (finTestInput) {
    finTestInput.value  = "0.00";
}
else {
    alert ("The target input does not exist yet!")
}
```

Note that if you use *Firebug* (you should), change the `alert()`s to `unsafeWindow.console.log()`s.

---

For issue 2, use the `waitForKeyElements` utility.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664942/331508), for example.

---

For issue 3, There is little we can do without access to the page to suss out the proper sequence of events.
Give us access to the page, or Use Firebug (and the Events panel) to figure it out, or maybe a snapshot of both the page's HTML, and the page's JS files, at [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) will be enough (maybe).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  The problem is not @include unfortunately.  I will experiment with waitForKeyElements.

Comment: Forgot to respond with resolution.  It was a problem with data being AJAX'd in.  I just used a 1 second timeout.  Thanks Brock