# how to know when the change of a dynamic page is fully loaded (from a userscript)?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

On `facebook.com`, where clicking on a 'link' *appears* to load a new page but (I believe) really just updates the existing page with new code, *how can I know when that new content is fully loaded*?  For example, when you go to `facebook.com`, you start at your 'home' page (the news feed). When you click on your name in the navbar you're taken to `facebook.com/yourname`.  However, it's not really a *new* page as a userscript doesn't get reloaded.

Because of this I wrote a little checker for my userscript that watches to see if the current href of the page has changed:

```
var startURL;
var curURL;

function main() {
    startURL = window.location.href;
    console.log("initial page. src: "+startURL);
    setInterval(checkfornewpage, 500);
}

function checkfornewpage() {
    curURL = window.location.href;

    if(curURL != startURL) {
        console.log("new page. src: "+curURL);
        // do something
        startURL = curURL;
    }
}

main();
```

This works fine and notifies me when the page has changed. But when trying to then access elements within that new page I'm finding that what I get back is from the old page.  I presume this is because even though the `window.location.href` has changed, the rest of the page isn't fully loaded.

So then I decided to look for some content on the new page that I know will change to clue me into whether the new content is fully loaded. I chose the `body` tag classes because the list of classes for `body` is always different with each new page. I wrote a function to watch for this, but even after the `body` class list has fully changed, my queries are still bringing up old page data.

I also tried calling `load()` on the `body` element, but that never fires.

I don't want to use some kind of generic `setTimeout` that just waits long enough...I want to know precisely when it's loaded so I can move forward immediately.  Ideas?

Comment: This is for Chrome userscripts, right?  (I have FF Greasemonkey code for this but haven't ported it to GrabAll's browser yet.)

Comment: i want it to work on both, but yes, i'm aimed at chrome right now

Comment: brock, any hints on how you did it in FF would be appreciated. i keep trying all kinds of various checks on the new content but nothing is reliable so far.

Comment: Use the `the waitForKeyElements()` utility similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10664942/331508) (and others).  Optionally, trigger off of the `hashchange` event -- but this is probably not necessary. ... ... Finally, your last three questions seem like duplicates.  You might consider deleting one or two and editing the survivors, lest a moderator smite ye.

Comment: thx for the leads.  and point taken on the dupes...didn't mean to keep rewriting the same question...they seemed different and more developed in the moment than they do now. i deleted one and requested deletion of the other, as this one seems more on point than those two.