# How to inject a button that will execute a function?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I'm having real difficulties using Greasemonkey and Firefox javascript to inject a button that, when selected, will execute a function.

For example, I am trying to place the button right after the "Unanswered" button on [the SO "Ask a Question" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

I wish it to run a function that will do *anything*, say `alert ("Hello World")` or `console.log('TEST start')`, for example.

Can someone please post up some sample code to make this work?  Once I have a working sample, then I should be able to go from there.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for this kind of thing is:

2. Determine the HTML structure of the content you want to modify.
3. Add or change your new content. Note that [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes it so much easier.
4. Add, modify, and/or delete javascript event listeners for your new content.
5. if the target content is added via AJAX methods, use [AJAX-compensating techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664942/331508).

For [your example page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask):

Inspecting with *Firebug* shows that the <kbd>Unanswered</kbd> "button" HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="nav mainnavs">
  <ul>
    ...
    <li>
      <a href="/unanswered" id="nav-unanswered">Unanswered</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So we will add a "button" like this:

```
<div class="nav mainnavs">
  <ul>
    ...
    <li>
      <a href="/unanswered" id="nav-unanswered">Unanswered</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="gmOurFirstButton">Log something</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

We'll activate it with [jQuery's `.click()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=click).

For this page and this button, we do not need to worry about AJAX.

Putting it all together, **a complete working script** looks like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add a simple button to a page
// @include  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var unansweredBtn   = $("#nav-unanswered");

//-- Add our button.
unansweredBtn.parent ().after (
    '<li><a href="#" id="gmOurFirstButton">Log something</a></li>'
);

//-- Activate the button.
$("#gmOurFirstButton").click ( function () {
    console.log ("Something.");
} );
```